# Add additional text at the end of a string in an array item

Tags: swift

Would like to add an additional text at the end of an existing text in an array-item. The code which I have till now looks like:

```
for var i = 0; i < arrMain.count; i++ {

    if (arrMain[i] as NSString).containsString("#ID-001") {

        println("OK")
        // Add additional text (eg. "Test") at the end of #ID-001 

    }  
}
```

Every tried combination overwrites me #ID-001...

Comment: What's the type of `arrMain` ?

Comment: Sorry, `var arrMain: [AnyObject] = []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var arrMain:[AnyObject] = ["#ID-001"]

for var i = 0; i < arrMain.count; i++ {
    if (arrMain[i] as NSString).containsString("#ID-001") {
        arrMain[i] = (arrMain[i] as String) + "Test"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx @rintaro, works like a charm! Also thanks to all for the different solutions. Will study them also!

Answer (score 0):

Either do this with the `for`-loop you already have, e.g.

```
var x = [ "a", "b", "c" ]

for index in 0 ..< x.count
{
    if x[index] == "b"
    {
        x[index] += "_hello"
    }
}
```

or use Swift's `map` function:

```
let y = x.map({ value -> String in return value == "b" ? value + "_hello" : value })
```

Please note, that

1. The second example will make a copy of the array.
2. Your array needs to be a mutable array, e.g. `let x = [ ... ]` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand the question:

```
arrMain[i] = arrMain[i].stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("#ID-001", withString: "#ID-001Test")
```